# Using BQ regex to extract elements with "strings" as delimiters

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I'm having trouble building a BQ-regex expression that extracts a given item from a bunch of text with variable delimiters, in the form of a Key = Value expression.

A sample of the strings I'm talking about is:

`house = long island && house : @New Amsterdam @@ house = Texas`

The token delimiters and key delimiters are known.
In this case:

```
Token delimiters = {' = ' |  ' : @'}
key delimiters =  { && | @@ }
```

I want the result

```
long island
New Amsterdam
Texas
```

`REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL("house = long island && house : @New Amsterdam", regex);`

I'm having trouble with the regex:
`house(( = )|( : @))[^(&&|@@)]*(&&|@@)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(txt, 'house\W*([^&@:]*[^&@:\s])')
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/S8ejf5/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```sql
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  house                    'house'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \W*                      non-word characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-
                           9, _) (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^&@:]*                  any character except: '&', '@', ':' (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^&@:\s]                 any character except: '&', '@', ':',
                             whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below example

```
with t as (
  select 'house = long island && house : @New Amsterdam @@ house = Texas' txt  
)
select result
from t,
unnest(split(regexp_replace(txt, r'[=&:@]', ''), 'house')) result
where result != ''
```

with output

[image]

Or more generic solution

```
with t as (
  select 'house = long island && house : @New Amsterdam @@ house = Texas' txt  
)
select 
  arr[offset(0)] as key,
  arr[offset(1)] as value
from t,
unnest(split(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(txt, r' && | @@ ', '|||'), r' = | : @', '&&&'), '|||')) kv,
unnest([struct(split(kv, '&&&') as arr)])
```

with output

[image]